# Is there any way to see the conversation log in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm using games to learn foreign languages (currently German) so I'd like to rewind and look at the conversation log if possible. Sometimes the conversation also goes by too fast. However, I didn't find any option to do so. Is there any option or mod (I'm playing on PC) that would help me achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't any way to do this in game. There is also no mod that allows you to replay conversations. I went through all of the audio and UI mods in nexusmods and couldn't find any that allowed this.

There was also a couple steam forum posts that talked about rewinding dialogue and the closest answer that was actually given was to create a save state or quicksave before your conversations so you can always quickload and redo the conversations.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what decisions you have made by looking at the quest log the bard will give a different telling of the story depending on what choices you made.